# duda con variables en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo un problema, tengo una variable a nievel de clase, mediante un metodo le asigno un valor, pero si quiero usar ese valor desde otro metodo no lo tiene.

como tengo que hacer??

```
public class Muestra{
     
          int numero=0;
public void metodo1(){
   int = 22;
 }


public void metodo2(){
    
    console.write(numero)<--- aca muestra 0 por mas que haya ejecutado el metodo1 primero
}
}
```

Comment: int = 22;  que significa esto? Me parece que lo que estuviste haciendo es declarar una variable local dentro de metodo1() que se llama numero tambien, y por lo tanto tu propiedad numero no se actualiza

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar tu pequeño bloque de código tiene un error de sintaxis en el método 2, y en segundo lugar, al momento de imprimir la variable 'numero' no ha sido llamada desde el método 2, para que te imprima 22 tendría que ser algo como esto (Main viene a ser como metodo2):

```
public class Program
{
    static int numero=0;
    
    public static void metodo1(){
        numero = 22;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
       metodo1();
       Console.WriteLine(numero);
    }
}
```

Salida:

> 22

Answer (score 1):

Esto deberia funcionarte. Tu error creo que fue que en el metodo 1 estabas declarando una variable local con el nombre de numero tambien, y por lo tanto tu propiedad numero (a nivel de la clase) no se actualizaba

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Muestra muestra = new Muestra();
        muestra.metodo1();
        muestra.metodo2();
    }
}

public class Muestra
{
    int numero = 0;
    public void metodo1()
    {
        numero = 22;
    }

    public void metodo2()
    {
        Console.Write(numero);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

La salida en la consola es 22

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria la estructura que debería tener tu proyecto, el error esta inicialmente en metodo1, estas llamando al tipo de dato de numero, no a la variable numero, por ese motivo no toma el valor que le estas asignando.

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Muestra muestra = new Muestra();
      muestra.metodo1();
      muestra.metodo2();
    }
  }
}

public class Muestra 
{
  int numero=0;

  public void metodo1()
  {
    numero = 22;//Acá estaba la equivocación, igual esta es la estructura que deberia tener.
  }

  public void metodo2(){

    Console.Write(numero); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.